# Programmatically get the execution order of objects inside a method?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

I have this piece of code (taken from ProfStef, but can be any method of any class). How do i **programmatically** get the order in which the objects are executed by Squeak/Pharo.

I *know* the order of execution from smalltalk documentation, but what if i need this information inside an app i'm building. Essentially use it to build an execution map to show the difference between how the code looks and how it is executed.

PS. I need this done on a massive scale... i can't do this by hand.

```
tutorial: aTutorialClass lesson: aSelector 
    | tutorial | 
    tutorial := aTutorialClass new. 
    self player tutorial: tutorial. 
    self tutorial: aTutorialClass lessonAt: (tutorial indexOfLesson: aSelector).
```

The output would be a tree something similar to this

something dothis

anotherobject [something dothis]

finalobject [ anotherobject [something do this] ]. // this is how the original code looked like.

Answer (score 5):

Check out our [AST interpreter](http://smalltalkhub.com/#!/~dh83/ast-interpreter) that will give you fine-grained control over the execution of Smalltalk code.

With underlying AST as execution format it is very easy to map the currently executed code back to the source code.

Comment: It seems you are right, http://magaloma.seasidehosting.st/AST-Core
It seems to have all the classes needed. Also from what i've read when it compiles it does so being "dumb" and you could use it to generate execution trees for example code also.
Sent you an e-mail from the contact sheet at your website to extend the discussion if you have the time.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bytecode interpreter in Pharo and several other dialects. In Pharo, have a look at ContextPart class>>trace:on:. Here's an example to run:

```
ContextPart trace: [3 factorial]
```

Comment: Wow, I never saw this answer when you added it. Just tested it now, quite interesting. I tried ContextPart trace: [Transcript open] and it show what it executes to get that done.